# LaTeX does not generate the aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files

I am executing the following command in the terminal, but that does not generate the `*.aux` file:

```
pdflatex main.tex
```

Why is it not generating the `main.aux` file?

Comment: The auxiliary file is not written, if `\nofiles` was used or if the compilation finishes (on purpose or because of error) before `\begin{document} `.

Comment: Why was this tagged as `latex3` ?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, thanks `\nofile` was the issue. Thank you :)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer latex3 was tagged by mistake :(

Comment: Are you using the res document class, perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The writing of the `.aux` files in LaTeX is controlled by switch `\if@filesw` (`w` short for writable). The command `\nofiles` sets the switch to false to prevent the rewriting of the auxiliary files.

The main `.aux` file is opened for writing in `\begin{document}`. If the LaTeX job does not reach this point, for example, because of an error or on purpose,
the auxiliary files are also not written.

Comment: not that it matters (or is documented anywhere) but I think `@filesw` is short for `file`  - `switch`  not `files` - `writable` :-)

Comment: so if `\nofiles` command is not there, writing will happen by default or not?

Comment: @vipin8169 The `.aux` files are written by default unless turned off.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek where are they written to? i could not find them in the folder which contained the .tex file

Comment: @vipin8169 There are lots of possible reasons: no LaTeX format, an hidden `\nofiles` or `\@fileswfalse`, end of the TeX job before `\begin{document}` is executed, option setting (`-output-directory` in TeX Live) with a different output directory, ...